# Dynamic sections of Words documents and mapping to XML documents

Tags: vsto

I've been working on generating Word documents by using XML, an XSD schema, and a Word document project.  The simple scenario is an invoice with invoice line items.  I'm able to create content controls and by using the tutorials at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398244.aspx), I've been able to pop open a document and see the top level items, such as billing address, shipping address, etc.  My question now, though, is I'm getting into the dynamic part, the part where the invoice line items are displayed.  An invoice obviously has one or more invoice line items.  I don't see any datagrid-like object that I just bind a list to, so I started going down the route of finding where the table that should contain the invoice line items begins, and start adding PlainTextControls to the document.  This requires that I find the exact paragraph location to start inserting and I'm not sure if it will work longterm if the document ever changes.  Here's the relavent code:

```
Document vstoDoc = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(this.Application.ActiveDocument);
this.Paragraphs[47].Range.InsertParagraphBefore();
this.Paragraphs[47].Range.Select();
PlainTextContentControl ctl = vstoDoc.Controls.AddPlainTextContentControl("textControl1");
ctl.PlaceholderText = "Enter your first name";
```

With this code, I can start to work on adding invoice line items to the document, but this feels like a hack, keeping track of the which paragraph I'm on, and then what happens when I have too many lines for the table that I've created?  Do I start adding lines to the document through code?

Before I go too far down this rabbit hole, I wanted to make sure that this was the prescribed method and I just have to suck it up and keep track of paragraphs, lines, etc.  Am I on the right track or should I be doing something different?

Comment: the vsto/word ole stuff is rusty but can't you use a bookmark? I believe they are named and you can jump to them. And if they are gone you can inform the user. From a bookmark you have a Range so you can do the other stuff you need

Comment: That seems like a good method.  I also found that VSTO allows you to do a .Tables and I should be able to get at the table and add rows when necessary.  Just looking for advice from people who've done this before and can say one way might be easier to maintain long term.